# subclasses with the same name in making an OWL ontology

Tags: owl, ontology, topbraid-composer

I'd like to make an ontology of the XML code below:

```
<InterfaceList>
    <EventInputs>
      <Event Name="INIT" Comment="Initialization Request">
        <With Var="MODE" />
      </Event>
      <Event Name="REQ" Comment="Update Request">
        <With Var="MODE" />
      </Event>
    </EventInputs>
    <EventOutputs>
      <Event Name="CNF" Comment="Update Confirmation">
        <With Var="LED1" />
      </Event>
    </EventOutputs>
</InterfaceList>
```

I built a superclass InterfaceList with the subclasses of EventInputs and EventOutputs but the problem occurs when it comes to subclasses: "Event" and "With".
since in the owl ontology it is not possible to create subclasses with the same name, what would be the suggestion about the subclass of "Event" and "With" that differs in EventInputs and EventOutputs

Comment: Just give it more meaningful names (aka URIs) `InputEvent` and `OutputEvent`?

Comment: this code is not the ontology I want to make the ontology out of this existing xml code and the "event" must be the subclass of more than one class.

Comment: And why is this a problem? I don't get it. A class can have multiple superclasses in OWL

Comment: Use different namespaces for distinct classes, then the fact that the last part of the IRI is identical becomes irrelevant. If the example you shared does not show the features you want to implement, you need to provide an example better fitting the question.